# How do I fire the SelectionChanged event in datagrid when there is only one row

Tags: events, xaml, mvvm-light

How do I fire the SelectionChanged event in datagrid when there is only one row.

Example, I have in my view the following:

But once you've selected an item I can not re-launch the event because it is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my xaml code i have:

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
  <cmd:EventToCommand
     Command="{Binding myCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
     CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=datagrid}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
  <cmd:EventToCommand
     Command="{Binding myCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
     CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=datagrid}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to depend on click event adding a condition inside that for the row number.